# phonegap/dreamweaver local form storage

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, dreamweaver

I'm very new to programming and to phonegap.  I have html background.  I have made a small android app in dreamweaver CS5.5 which will store data locally.  My app is working fine where I can go to different pages.  I need to save the form now.  Can someone help me with the steps that I need to do this? I hope its not super difficult and I can understand it.  It also uses mobile jquery but I haven't edited anything in it.

Here's the form that I have. I want to have this info saved on this or another page where I can go back and edit later as well.

```
<form action="" method="get" id="customerDetail">
<label for="name">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" /></label>
<label for="email">
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"></label>
<label for="comment">
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Insert comments"></textarea>
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

To store and retrieve data, you need to create database using PHP and MySQL, and of course a server that supports MySQL.

However, you can test your scripts locally on your machine using [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), but still you need to create database and tables where you can store your data permanently, or you can download ready made database for testing purposes.

Once you install XAMPP on your machine you can create database and tables, then you connect your database with DreamWeaver to act like an online server.

I hope I have been of help.

Answer (score 0):

You should search for Phonegap with Sqllite, that should lead you to some useful links.